# Schema Compare SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER for View with an Index

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, view, indexing

I am using a VS 2010 SP1 database project with a SQL Server 2005 database. I need to create a view, and a unique clustered index on that view. When Schema Compare generates the script (with the option to use SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER checked), it sets QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF, issues a GO, creates the view, issues a GO, sets QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON, issues a GO, then creates the index. The CREATE INDEX step fails with:

Cannot create index. Object 'myView' was created with the following SET options off: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'.

I tried un-checking the Schema Compare option, and although the generated script no longer sets QUOTED_IDENTIFIER either on or off anywhere, but the CREATE INDEX step still fails with the same error.

The database had the SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER property set to false, so I altered the database to SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE. However, a subsequent attempt to run the generated script still fails with the same error.

How can I get Schema Compare to generate a script that works?

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, I'm going to dig up an old one here, but, I believe this is because you have to set Quoted Identifier at the object level. Further it must be on if you are dealing with computed columns or indexed views.